# I copied a List to a temp ist. I delete properties from the Copied List and properties of the original List Changes

Tags: java, list, object

i am really confused right now.
i have a List of "Order" objects. They have things like orderNumber and so on..
Our Professor wants a view where you have just short informations about this Order.
And if you search for the ID you need to see all information.
So i thought i just make a copie of the orginal list and delete some properties there. But somehow the properties are changing in the original list. Can you please help?

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/norGn.png)

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Both lists reference the same objects. If we change one element in `odersList`, it also changes in `temp` (since they are the same object).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to examine shallow copy and deep copy. You can read differences between these terms in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deep-shallow-lazy-copy-java-examples/).

Shortly,
`shallow copy`, the reference of objects is kept at the memory address of the original. Changes made to the copied will also affect the original. It is a faster copying process. In `deep copy`, it is kept in two separate references. Only the data in it is transferred to another. The change does not affect the original data. It is slower than shallow.